# Extract entries from a Google Docs file into different parts or files

Tags: text, google-drive

In a Google Document I keep a journal. Entries are separated by days, although I sometimes write very often and at other times not so often.

The journal is a continuous document where each entry has the day written in bold and 14 pt while the entry text is not bold and 10 pt.

I wonder if there is any way to extract the text into separated parts or notes, each one corresponding to each different day.

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to write a script using Google Apps   Script.  Getting started: http://code.google.com/googleapps/appsscript/guide_getting_started.html  (the example is for google spreadsheets, but the mechanics are the same for documents)

The relevant API is here:
http://code.google.com/googleapps/appsscript/service_document.html

Not sure, but it sounds like you want to loop over the paragraphs via getParagraphs() looking for your entry headers.

Comment: yes, that is the point. I will have a look at it. Although I can also convert the gdoc a simple RTF file, and from there do also the conversion. For that I do not need google, but other things. Will keep you up to date.

Answer (score 1):

If the purpose is to organize the entries for easy accessibility, you can have a "[Table of contents](http://docs.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=106342)".